# Python Appending Not Working

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to create a program to take text and change it to a three digit code. In order to do this, I'm adding a "Uppercase Indicator' in the form of a 1 or 0, however my list.append() only seems to add one 1 or 0 to the end of the output:

Code:

```
CODE = {'A': 'aaa',     'B': 'aba',   'C': 'aca', 
        'D': 'ada', 'E': 'aab', 'F': 'abb',
        'G': 'acb', 'H': 'adb', 'I': 'aac',
        'J': 'abc', 'K': 'acc', 'L': 'adc',
        'M': 'aad', 'N': 'abd', 'O': 'acd',
        'P': 'add', 'Q': 'baa', 'R': 'bba',
        'S': 'bca', 'T': 'bda', 'U': 'bab',
        'V': 'bbb', 'W': 'bcb', 'X': 'bdb',
        'Y': 'bac', 'Z': 'bbc',

        '0': 'bcc', '1': 'bdc', '2': 'bad',
        '3': 'bbd', '4': 'bcd', '5': 'bdd',
        '6': 'caa', '7': 'cba', '8': 'cca',
        '9': 'cda',

        '+': 'cab', '-': 'cbb', '*': 'ccb',
        '/': 'cdb', '%': 'cbc', '>': 'ccc',
        '<': 'cdc',

    ' ': 'cad', '.': 'cbd', ',': 'ccd',
    """'""": 'cdd', '!': 'daa', '?': 'dba',
        }

def main():
    transmit = [];

    msg = raw_input('MESSAGE: ')
    for char in msg:
        transmit.append(CODE[char.upper()])
        if char == char.upper():
          transmit.append('1')
        else:
          transmit.append('0')

    print ''.join(transmit)


if "true" == "true":
    main()
```

(sorry, can't get the code to work right.)

When this is my input:

```
Message: Hello
```

This is my output:

```
adbaabadcadcacd0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your desired output, not just what the program is printing?

Comment: `transmit.append(CODE[char.upper()])` this indent is incorrect

Comment: it looks like the indentation is probably off, is the `if char == char.upper():` inside or after the for loop?

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Mixed tabs and spaces, among other issues. Fix that, and you'll fix your bug.

Comment: that's an interesting case: in the repl.it, we can see that the `if` block has an extra tab, and python considers that as one _less_ tab

Answer (score 0):

https://repl.it/HGpz/4

It looks like your code wasn't correctly indented:

```
def main():
    transmit = [];

    msg = raw_input('MESSAGE: ')
    for char in msg:
    #         transmit.append(CODE[char.upper()])
        transmit.append(CODE[char.upper()])
        if char == char.upper():
    #     transmit.append('1')
            transmit.append('1')
        else:
    #     transmit.append('0')
            transmit.append('0')

    print ''.join(transmit)
```

Comment: `#     transmit.append('1')` those are not necessary to change